# The union and intersection of rules in Arules does arithmetically make sense

Tags: r, apriori, arules

The simple Maths of *union(setA,setB)= setA + setB - intersect(setA,setB)* is not valid

What am I missing here?

This is the summary of my two rules sets.

```
> setA
set of 625 rules
 
> setB
set of 622 rules 

> union(setA,setB)
set of 626 rules 

> intersect(setA,setB)
set of 174 rules 

> setdiff(setA,setB)
set of 451 rules 

> setdiff(setB,setA)
set of 448 rules
```

Exported Rules

[setA](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VDH-hUFsS2OBQBmCkzHUlSy3OnoXDQcY/view?usp=sharing)

[setB](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q4JFWsIH1SJKYwI-feNv8vZWRggvu7Na/view?usp=sharing)

RModel

[setA.Rdata](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fccJ6FZ4cUsMrIRrsmMs1G2J9K1HeRhj/view?usp=sharing)

[setB.Rdata](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hy0xWKl9sYb5nJFXmQmEiEFwXdHOVPdZ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can your provide a small minimum data of `setA` and `setB` that can reproduce your  problem? That will be convient for us to verify the problem.

Comment: Added links to data set. These are the entire set of records.

Comment: What's the result of `class(setA` and `class(setB)`? Usually, `union`,`setdiff` and `intersect` are designed for single vector, here yours `setA` and `setB` includes multi vectors.

Comment: I have used Set Operations in arules; https://rdrr.io/cran/arules/man/sets.html. Which allows set operations on sets of associations (e.g., rules, itemsets) and itemMatrix.

Comment: To answer your query on class > class(setA) 
[1] "rules"
attr(,"package")
[1] "arules"
> class(setB)
[1] "rules"
attr(,"package")
[1] "arules"
>

Comment: I have added the R model as well

Comment: Hi, you put 2 times setA.Rdata and we don't have setB

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with `arules`. Hope others can answer your question.

Comment: Update the link for setB.Rdata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky problem.

```
load("setA.Rdata")
load("setB.Rdata")

all.equal(itemLabels(setA), itemLabels(setB))   
[1] "Lengths (261, 263) differ (string compare on first 261)"
[2] "167 string mismatches"
```

You have two rule sets that use different item encodings (i.e., a different order for the items). This happens if you mine them from different datasets and do not take care that the item encoding is the same.

arules expects that the sets are encoded in the same way without checking. I think a check needs to be added.

You can fix your rule sets by recoding them to use the same itemLabels:

```
itemLabels <- union(itemLabels(setA), itemLabels(setB))

setA_fixed <- new("rules",
  lhs = recode(lhs(setA), itemLabels = itemLabels), 
  rhs = recode(rhs(setA), itemLabels = itemLabels)
  )

setB_fixed <- new("rules",
  lhs = recode(lhs(setB), itemLabels = itemLabels), 
  rhs = recode(rhs(setB), itemLabels = itemLabels)
)
```

Now you get the expected result:

```
length(union(setA_fixed, setB_fixed))
[1] 626
length(c(setA_fixed, setB_fixed)) - length(intersect(setA_fixed, setB_fixed))
[1] 626
```

Comment: Thank you very much... Thanks for taking time to explain this and resolve.